# Are the two formulas for computing the output shape of a convolution equivalent? Computing the floor before or after adding $1$?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

I've come across two different formulas in my studies to calculate the output shape of a convolution.
Below, $I$ is the input image size, $K$ the filter size and $S$ the stride.
$$
\lfloor \frac{I - K + 2P}{S} \rfloor + 1
$$
and
$$
\lfloor \frac{I - K + 2P}{S} + 1 \rfloor
$$

I've computed quite a few examples and I come up with the same results. Are these equivalent?

Edit: Hmm, reasoning I am thinking that they must be equivalent, because the fractional component is only produced by the first term, so that always gets thrown away. The floor of 1 is always 1, so it shouldn't make a difference.

Many thanks in advance!